# Sending out e-mail and updating table with AJAX in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently making a WordPress plugin where I want to be able to send e-mail to people from a list. I have made the form (id: campaign), and all checkboxes seems to work. The form submit to itself with a query string, so in the same file I have a if-then that check if this query string has some data.

I have made an admin page with a sub form underneath that lists all e-mail addresses:

[image]

I want the script to send out e-mails to each e-mail that has been selected, updating the MySQL table that the mail has been sent, and showing a counter on the page (i.e. '#/15 e-mails sent'). I know how to make this script in plain PHP, but my lack of knowledge with AJAX is the problem.

So this is what I want:

1. The form sending data to itself (same PHP file) - this is working.
2. Starting the AJAX script based on the selected checkboxes
3. Sending out e-mails and updating the SQL table based on a timer (to avoid spam)
4. Showing real-time counter

This is what I have so far:

```
    <div id="feedback"></div>
    <?php


    add_action('wp_ajax_sendPromo', 'sendPromo');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendPromo', 'sendPromo'); // not really needed

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#campaign').submit(ajaxSubmit);

    function ajaxSubmit(){

        var campaign = jQuery(this).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: campaign,
            success:function(data){
                jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
    </script>
    <?php

    function sendPromo(){

    global $wpdb;

    $recepients = $_GET['recepients_email']; // array of checkboxes
    for($i=0; $i < count($recepients); $i++){
        mail($recepients[$i], $subject, $message, $headers); // mail is being sent
        if($wpdb->update('wp_ap_promo',array(
        'sent'=>1
        ), array( 'email' => '" . $recepients[$i] . "' ))===FALSE){

            echo "Error";

        }
        else {
            echo "Successfully sent to '".$recepients[$i]. "', row ID is ".$wpdb->update_id;

        }
    }
    die();
}
```

One of the problems seems to be that the JS isn't being run because the page is reloading (it is meant to reload, because I want the user to see a plain page with the send counter.

Comment: What do you mean by "the page is reloading"? Are you submitting the form data via AJAX or not?

Comment: @76484 Thats pretty much my problem. When it submit the form to itself a page load is perform, so it can show a new page with the e-mail sending process. I just don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Which do you want, a full page request or an AJAX request?

Comment: Maybe a combo is best? First a full page request where the AJAX request is performed. The reason for the AJAX is to have a counter for each sql update.

Comment: I do not understand whether you want to submit all of the checked values at once or if you want to queue them and submit them individually, one after another.

Comment: @76484 Individually, in case the process is stopped (ie. window closed).

Comment: Well in that case you will need to add quite a bit more complexity than what you have here. You will need to queue your items and then create some sort of recursive method for clearing your queue that will make an AJAX request for the first item, wait for the response, and then send the next item.

Comment: @76484 I'm really on thin ice here, and am considering more and more to use PHP only, but it would definitely be more user friendly to do each request individually with a counter. So a solution with AJAX would be preferable. But isn't the array of checkboxes some kind of a queue?

Comment: Not if you send them all together. Right now, your form submit handler sends one AJAX request to your PHP script. This request contains all of the selected email addresses. There is no way to time these individually - they are all contained within one request.

Comment: Well, the script I posted doesn't work at all, as it is a combination of a full page request with a AJAX request, and they doesn't comunicate/work together. But wouldn't a timer/wait within the `for($i=0; $i < count($recepients); $i++){` work?

Comment: Work to achieve *what*? To increase the response time from the server? Certainly. But this does nothing to indicate to the client-side which individual item from the array is currently getting processed. I think you are not fully understanding the difference between what is executing on the server and what is on the client. I fear you are in for a world of headache if you continue to pursue this solution.

Comment: @76484 I have seen some plugins with import/export functions that has these kinds of real time counters. I know my script is far from the real deal but I think I'm steady with server vs. client. The easiest way to make this is with server side only, but I need a slight delay (to avoid mass-sending), so with a server side only it would look like the page is loading really slow, and might end up with the user closing the page in the middle of the process.

Comment: Yes. This is why you shouldn't put delays in a script that generates a web page response. Moving the submission request to AJAX solves nothing. The user would just think that the AJAX request is taking too long and close the page. (By the way, the user closing the browser window *does not* kill the server-side process.) I think you will need to move the sending of the emails to a separate script, one that gets called by a cron job that executes every few minutes.

Comment: @76484 Ah, ok. I have also been thinking about cron job, but have tried to avoid it as I want high compatibility for the users of my plugin. Maybe a solution could be to use fully server side but with a fake JavaScript time that is not related to the sql query but work with the same delay as the server side?